# Xaml Converter and displaying "Select a Date" in the DateTimePicker

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, converters

In a wpf application, i bound some dateTimePicker.
I would like to create a converter in order to display the famous line "select a date" in the dateTilmePicker when the date is 31/12/2999.

I created a converter :

```
    public class DateConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value == null)
                return DateTime.MinValue;

            if (((DateTime)value).ToShortDateString() == "31/12/2999")
                return DateTime.MinValue;

            DateTime returnVal;

            if (DateTime.TryParse(value.ToString(), out returnVal))
            {
                if (returnVal != DateTime.MinValue)
                    return returnVal;
                else
                    return DateTime.MinValue;
            }
            else
                return DateTime.MinValue;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value == null)
                return DateTime.MinValue;

            DateTime val;
            if (value.ToString() == "31/12/2999")
                return DateTime.MinValue;

            if (DateTime.TryParse(value.ToString(), out val))
                return val;
            else
                return DateTime.MinValue;
        }

    }
```

Here is my XAMl :

```
<DatePicker x:Name="DateTimePicker_Date"  Text="{Binding  RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource DateConverter}, Path=SelectedDate, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, TargetNullValue='', ValidatesOnDataErrors=False}"/>
```

My problem is when my date is 31/12/2999, the value written in the DateTimePicker is "01/01/0001" instead of the famous sentence "Select a date".

Anyone have some ideas please ?

Thanks a lot,

Best regards,

Nixeus

Answer (score 0):

The code snippet

```
if (((DateTime)value).ToShortDateString() == "31/12/2999")
            return DateTime.MinValue;
```

should be changed to

```
if (((DateTime)value).ToShortDateString() == "31/12/2999")
            return "select a date";
```

in your `Convert` method.

Answer (score 0):

Here i have changed the Converter for testing where a Selected Date is below or equal to Today's date then just return the date else return null.

So when we return null the SelectedDate property of DatePicker it will trigger the attached Trigger and set the Text  to Select a Date.

```
 <DatePicker x:Name="datepicker" Text="{Binding  RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource DateConverter}, Path=SelectedDate, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=False}">
            <DatePicker.Style>
                <Style TargetType="DatePicker">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="SelectedDate" Value="{x:Null}">
                            <Setter Property="Text" Value="Select A Date"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </DatePicker.Style>
        </DatePicker>



 public class DateConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value == null)
                return null;

            if (((DateTime)value).ToShortDateString() == "31/12/2999")
                return null;

            DateTime returnVal;

            if (DateTime.TryParse(value.ToString(), out returnVal))
            {

                if (returnVal <= DateTime.Today) // to check only
                    return returnVal;
                //else if (returnVal != DateTime.MinValue)
                //    return returnVal;
                else
                    return null;
            }
            else
                return null;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {


            if (value == null)
                return null;

            DateTime val;
            if (value.ToString() == "31/12/2999")
                return null;

            if (DateTime.TryParse(value.ToString(), out val))
                return val;
            else
                return null;


        }

    }
```

Change the converter code as per your requrement.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in xaml only. No need to write converter. I have even removed the Text binding

```
<DatePicker x:Name="DateTimePicker_Date">
    <DatePicker.Style>
        <Style TargetType="DatePicker">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=SelectedDate}" Value="31/12/2999">
                    <Setter Property="SelectedDate" Value="{x:Null}" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DatePicker.Style>
</DatePicker>
```

P.S. Please make sure that your date format is correct(31/12/2999 vs 12/31/2999)